# Print de array php

Tags: php, array

Boníssima tarde á todos!!! :D Eu estou criando uma página em php que me informa o meu ip local, estou fazendo isto através do comando: `shell_exec('ipconfig')` até ai tudo bem pois ele retorna o ip da minha máquina certinho, porém ele não retorna apenas o **ip**, mas também Endereço **Ipv6**, **Ipv4**, máscara de sub-rede, Gateway... enfim retorna a turma toda aí como quando digitamos o comando `ipconfig`  no Prompt de comando do PC.

Eis meu dilema! eu quero que ele imprima na tela apenas o **Ip**, mas ele está imprimindo uma lista e no meio desta lista se encontra o meu ip. Então a mente brilhante aqui achou que poderia imprimir só o ip se a lista fosse um array, atribui o valor retornado pelo comando a uma variável array e imprimi a variável e o óbvio aconteceu, ele imprimiu:

```
  Array ( [0] => a turminha toda do resultado do comando ipconfig e blá blá blá )
```

toda a minha lista está como índice 0. Queria saber se há como dividir o array, para imprimir só o ip ou se há outro meio para imprimir só o ip desta lista.

Obrigada, se alguém souber fico muitíssimo agradecida :)

Lá vai o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>teste</title>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="60">
</head>
<body>
<?php 
$str = array(shell_exec('ipconfig'));

print_r($str);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Já tentou usar `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` ao invés do `ipconfig`?

Comment: Obrigada @zekk já tentei mas não deu certo ele retorna  ::1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o `exec` para essa finalidade, ao invés do `shell_exec`.

```
$exec = exec('ipconfig', $array);

if($exec){

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($array);
echo '</pre>';

}
```

Retornará:

```
array(15) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(29) "Configuração de IP do Windows"
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
  [4]=>
  string(43) "Adaptador de Rede sem Fio Conexão Local* 2:"
  [5]=>
  string(0) ""
  [6]=>
  string(67) "   Estado da mídia. . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : mídia desconectada"
  [7]=>
  string(48) "   Sufixo DNS específico de conexão. . . . . . :"
  [8]=>
  string(0) ""
  [9]=>
  string(32) "Adaptador de Rede sem Fio Wi-Fi:"
  [10]=>
  string(0) ""
  [11]=>
  string(48) "   Sufixo DNS específico de conexão. . . . . . :"
  [12]=>
  string(60) "   Endereço IPv4. . . . . . . .  . . . . . . . : 192.AAA.AAA.AAA"
  [13]=>
  string(62) "   Máscara de Sub-rede . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0"
  [14]=>
  string(60) "   Gateway Padrão. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.BBB.BBB.BBB"
}
```

Para obter o IPv4 bastaria usar isso:

> **/!\ Isso é uma gambiarra!**

```
foreach($array as $item){

    if (!!strpos($item, 'IPv4')) {
        list($descricao, $ip) = explode(': ', $item);
    }

}

echo $ip;
```

Resultado:

```
192.AAA.AAA.AAA
```

### Um outra solução:

Se deseja apenas obter o endereço de IP do servidor, pode usar duas alterativas.

**Obter o "Endereço IPv4":**

```
$nomeHost = gethostname();
$ip = gethostbyname($nomeHost);

echo $ip;
```

Resultado:

```
192.AAA.AAA.AAA
```

**Obter o "Endereço do Servidor":**

```
$ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];

echo $ip;
```

Resultado:

```
127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Muito obrigada a segunda opção `$nomeHost = gethostname();
$ip = gethostbyname($nomeHost);

echo $ip;`  funcionou perfeitamente só retornou o meu ip vlw :)