# Como obter o endereço de IP local usando PHP?

Tags: php, ip

Tenho uma aplicação no qual pretendo, afins de teste, obter o **endereço de IP** local da meu PC. Fiz uma breve pequisa e o vi que é possível resgata-lo usando o seguinte código:

```
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

Porém não funcionou pra mim que estou usando a `versão 5.6.26` do PHP. Sendo assim eu pergunto, é possível obter o **endereço IP** local através de uma página PHP? Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: eu uso 5.2.17 e funciona. Coloca no seu codigo  phpinfo();  e veja todas as informações em PHP Variables

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];

Comment: Veja isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143004/print-de-array-php/143010#143010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é possível nenhum servidor externo acessar o "IP local" (IP de uma rede interna), eu cheguei a comentar algo sobre isto aqui:

- [Algorítimo validação Mac Address](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166097/3635)

O máximo que um servidor externo (independente da linguagem que usa) vai conseguir é o IP do ISP (*Internet Service Provider* - Provedor de Serviço Internet), ou seja se 100 computadores compartilham a mesma "internet" todos terão o "mesmo IP" se usar `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`, pois na verdade o IP é da "conexão".

Não existe maneira prática de contornar isso, o exemplo que citaram nos comentários não funciona "nativamente":

```php
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
```

Ele não é uma variável do PHP e sim uma variável gerada pelos headers de um "cliente" (navegador, bot, etc) via http, por exemplo:

```
GET /pagina.php HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: MyBotFooBar1.0
X-Real-Ip: 10.0.0.105
```

Ou seja todas "variáveis" que começam com `HTTP_` são geradas a partir dos headers e isto não é uma maneira segura de verificar a autenticidade, ou seja é facilmente fraudável, já que os headers podem ser facilmente manipulados.

Raramente algum navegador vai enviar este o header `X-Real-Ip`, você teria que configura-los para fazerem isto usando um Add-on/extensão ou um "proxy", um trabalho muito grande que pode não valer o esforço.

Se o seu objetivo é usar isto para algum *"tipo de autenticação"* recomendo pensar em medidas como um aplicativo de celular com token (ou algo parecido) e dispensar de vez o uso de IPs.

> **Nota:**
>
> A dica sobre do `ipconfig` só funciona se o PHP estiver na máquina que deseja obter o endereço:
>
> `exec('ipconfig', $array);`
>
> Usar outros comandos também não funcionarão, como o `arp`, isto porque o PHP precisaria estar na mesma rede local que os computadores, o que acredito não ser o seu objetivo.